# Алгоритм, как расставить знаки сложения и вычитания между числами для получения определенного числа?

Tags: алгоритм

Дан набор чисел. Надо расставить между ними знаки сложения и вычитания, чтобы получившееся выражение было максимально близко к заданному числу.
Количество чисел не больше, чем 10<sup>4</sup>, а сами числа не превосходят 10<sup>4</sup> по модулю. Ограничение по времени: 1 секунда.

Полный перебор не проходит по времени.

Какие есть предложения?

Comment: Решить данную задачу за 1 секунду это не к нам, это вам к богу надо ;)

Comment: Динамика с квадратичной или лучше асимптотикой.

Comment: А откуда взялось ограничение по времени и такая странная задача? Вы решаете реальную проблему, или спихиваете нам олимпиадную задачу?

Comment: @VladD, не поверите, но это вполне реальная задача с реальными ограничениями. Данная зада была на тестировании в ШАДе.
Вот ссылка(задача F) : https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/655/problems/

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте такой вариант.

Отсортировать числа по убыванию, после чего последовательно вычитать их из нужного результата. Когда значение станет <=0 сменить оператор на +, как станет >0 снова на минус и т.д.

В конце инвертировать операции. То есть поменять все минусы на плюсы и наоборот.

**UPD** Либо же, чтоб в конце не инвертировать, начать с прибавления к нулю и сходиться вокруг заданного результата

**UPD2**

PHP 5.5

```
<?php
$values  = array();
$rawValues = array();
$target  = rand(0, 10000);
$current = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $rawValues[] = rand(-10000, 10000);
}
$time = microtime(true);
foreach ($rawValues as $value){
    $values[abs($value)] = $value;
}
krsort($values);
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $multiplier = $current > $target ? -1 : 1;
    if ($value < 0) $multiplier = -$multiplier;
    echo ($multiplier < 0 ? "-" : "+") . $value . "<br>";
    $current += $multiplier * $value;
}
echo "result " . $current . " target " . $target . " time " . (microtime(true) - $time);
```

> result 6265 target 6265 time 0.024444095652956
>
> result 8503 target 8501 time 0.024614095687866
>
> result 4126 target 4125 time 0.024505853652954
>
> result 5147 target 5146 time 0.025776863098145

**UPD3** 
Можно так, но сильно медленней(хотя в секунду укладывается)

```
<?php
$values  = array();
$target  = rand(0, 10000);
$current = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $values[] = rand(-10000, 10000);
}
$time = microtime(true);

usort($values, function ($a, $b) { return abs($a) < abs($b); });

foreach ($values as $value) {
    $multiplier = $current > $target ? -1 : 1;
    if ($value < 0) $multiplier = -$multiplier;
    echo ($multiplier < 0 ? "-" : "+") . $value . "<br>";
    $current += $multiplier * $value;
}
echo "result " . $current . " target " . $target . " time " . (microtime(true) - $time);
```

Comment: да, идея неплохая и я похожу пытался написать. Только вот я к текущему числу сразу и прибавлял, и вычитал новое число, тем самым храня не одну переменную current, а массив (который на каждом шаге мог увеличиваться в два раза) не повторяющихся элементов, которые могли получиться. И в конце смотрел что получилось, но эта реализация дала неправильный ответ на тестах почему-то :(

Comment: @marka_17 скорее всего потому, что у вас в исходных данных присутствуют отрицательные числа. Надо их отслеживать и соответственно менять знак операции. Сейчас попробую поправить и выложу.

Answer (score 0):

Решаю подобную задачу.
В процессе нашел следующее: [статья](http://lotos-khv.ru/programm/books/lek8.pdf)

Если непонятно при чем тут камни: 1ая куча - положительные числа, 2ая - отрицательные, разница весов - отклонения от нуля.

У меня еще нет эффективного решения задачи, но думаю что бы получить его следует использовать ограничение на числа. Если нет, задача идентична классической задаче о  [камнях](https://site.ada.edu.az/~medv/acm/Docs%20Timus/Volume%201/1005.htm).

Для удобства вот контрпример из 1ой статьи [36, 25, 12, 10, 8, 7, 1].